# Can't find 'stof' and 'stoi' in this scope on EC2 instance when running C++ application?

Tags: c++, amazon-ec2, makefile

I'm trying to compile a C++ application on an `r3.xlarge` EC2 instance. I installed g++ on the instance with the command `yum install gcc-c++`. However, I'm still getting a bunch of `error: ‘stof’ was not declared in this scope` and `error: ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope` messages when running `make`. I think this has something to do with C++11, but I'm fairly new to C++, so I'm not quite sure how to start trying to fix this. Here's my `Makefile` if it makes any difference:

`Makefile`:

```
CC = g++
ifeq ($(shell sw_vers 2>/dev/null | grep Mac | awk '{ print $$2}'),Mac)
    CFLAGS = -g -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -I./include/ -I/usr/X11/include -DOSX
    LDFLAGS = -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL \
        -L"/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries" \
        -lGL -lGLU -lm -lstdc++
else
    CFLAGS = -g -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -Iglut-3.7.6-bin
    LDFLAGS = -lglut -lGLU
    FLAGS += -O3
    FLAGS += -std=c++11
    FLAGS += -D_DEBUG -g Wall
endif

all: scene 
scene: scene.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o scene scene.o lodepng.o $(LDFLAGS)   

scene.o: Scene.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Scene.cpp -o scene.o

lodepng.o: lodepng.cpp lodepng.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c lodepng.cpp -o lodepng.o

clean: 
    $(RM) *.o scene
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to assume you already `#include <string>`?

Comment: Should that be `CFLAGS` rather than `FLAGS` when you specify `-std=c++11`? You're using `CFLAGS` when you compile.

Comment: Excellent, worked, thanks!